# How to display a variable with specified type on windbg

Tags: casting, windbg

I am using windbg to debug my application, but I can't find a command to dump a variable value  with specified type.

for example,  there  is a variable, say A, its type is int.
now I 'd like to dump variable A with uint type.

how to do it ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

dt is your friend

```
0:000> dt i
Local var @ 0x18f2cc Type int
0n-2
0:000> dt (uint) 0x18f2cc 
CrashTestD!UINT
0xfffffffe
```

If you want decimal output, Set Number Base 10

```
0:000> n 10
base is 10
0:000> dt (uint) 0x18f2cc 
CrashTestD!UINT
0n4294967294
```

Still wondering, use :

```
0:000> .formats 0xfffffffe
Evaluate expression:
  Hex:     fffffffe
  Decimal: -2
  Octal:   37777777776
  Binary:  11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110
  Chars:   ....
  Time:    unavailable
  Float:   low -1.#QNAN high 0
  Double:  2.122e-314
```

Much more [Here:](http://analyze-v.com/?p=814)

Comment: thanks. it works.  one more question: could I print it in the format of decimal number instead of Hex ?